# Json parser - need to skip few characters and parse - java

Tags: java, json

I am working with json responses,
Able to process json using json parser.

But in few cases,  json response will have word like
 'jquery-id99999999({json response})'

Here json parser is throwing error,  is it possible to handle this with json parser.

I want to exclude
 'jquery-id99999999('
and get json response alone

Comment: try to find why it is generating a json with this string jquery****, look into the documenation/tutorial of jquery there you may find something

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to fix the code that is generating the invalid JSON. If you can't do that, just remove the prefix before passing your JSON string to the parser.

```
invalidJsonResponse = 'jquery-id99999999({"key": "val"})';
validJson = invalidJsonResponse.match(/.*\((.*)\).*/)[1]; // -> '{"key": "val"}'
obj = JSON.parse(validJson); // -> Object {key: "val"}
// do something with obj
```